# When creating pack files, what heuristics does Git use to identify "similar" objects?

Tags: git

The git-scm book[1] says that while packing loose objects, Git looks for files that are **named** and **sized** similarly before deciding which files to delta against each other. Where can I find more details about this "heuristic"? Specifically, I wanted to know how the delta candidates and the sequence of deltas is identified.

[1] http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Packfiles

Comment: Probably the source code for `git` is the best reference... I've seen some write-ups about it, but none in great detail. It essentially involves sorting all objects into one big list, based on name, size, and a few other things, then running a sliding window down the list and comparing each object to the others within that window.